# custom control sensing accelchar

Tags: delphi, keyboard, controls, vcl, accelerator

I'm trying to figure how to make my custom control (based on static text) respond to accelerator key (delphi, which i use, names it accelchar) press. By responding i mean adding some code. Best i came up with is processing WM_SYSKEYUP and checking the caption and the character code manually. I suspect there must be a simpler and more reliable solution.

Comment: The Forms unit has code IsAccel, which may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say your control is based on TStaticText. If you peek into TStaticText (or its ancestor, TCustomStaticText actually), you will see a message handler that handles the default behavior of focusing another control:

```
procedure CMDialogChar(var Message: TCMDialogChar); message CM_DIALOGCHAR;
```

In its implementation, you can see how it verifies its own state:

```
if (FFocusControl <> nil) and Enabled and ShowAccelChar and
  IsAccel(Message.CharCode, Caption) then
```

In the base implmentation, the focuscontrol will be focused when that `if` is entered, but in your implementation, you can simply make a new message handler, with that same if in it, and add your own implementation to it.

Comment: Guess i could accept this, but i still have a few questions. How do i peek into tstatictext, tlabel, or whatever? Easy to get WM messages explanations on MS site, but difficult for CM/CN messages; how to find info on CM_dialogchar and others? Do you think code such as this will show any flaws?  `procedure mycontrol.CMDlgChr(var message:TCMDialogChar); begin
 if isaccel(message.charcode,caption) and showaccelchar and enabled and visible and ((message.keydata and $20000000)<>0) then begin
   {if not focused then} setfocus; domyjob***
 end else inherited end;`

Comment: looks i also lack talent for formatting the comments... anyway... another question is: is this approach really any different than the one i initially used? i wrote my own isaccel routine like `for i:=1 to pred(length(caption)) do if (caption[i]='&') and (caption[succ(i)]<>'&') then if (VkKeyScanExW(caption[succ(i)],GetKeyboardLayout(0)) and 767)=(message.wparam and 255) then ...`  and apart from the fact that my routine reacts on KeyUp while this one reacts on KeyPress i think they might be pretty similar.

Comment: They are pretty similar in the end, except "my" solution also takes over the message from the ancestor, and gets it in an earlier stage. Since it's your own control, it probably doesn't matter that much anyway, but I think my solution will always work, while your solution will not work anymore as soon as somebody assigns a focuscontrol to your component. Not a big deal, though, I guess.

Comment: When you Ctrl+Click a class, u should be taken to its declaration. Very useful for learning to just browse the code of VCL components. But I think the community edition of Delphi doesn't include all of those sources, unfortunately, so if you have that, maybe you can't view the source.

Comment: Right, no pas sources here, but i found them on my old computer in delphi 6 folder. Thx for the ctrl-click tip. Border flashing fixed by adding message result. Pagecontrol children reacting on invisible tabs solved by adding parent visibility check. Btw this ffocuscontrol is just active control, no need to dig into delphi 6, right? Thank you.

Comment: Focuscontrol is the control that is focused when you press the accel key. This is the way you can focus an edit by pressing the accel key of its associated label. TStaticText has that same functionality.